# Adding a Thread.sleep in my Selenium scripts is breaking the execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-java

It's a simple Selenium script where I am launching a URL and performing a couple of Click actions.
When I put a Thread.sleep(2000) between any of these few steps, execution breaks and I get an exception as shown below.

Dec 26, 2022 3:55:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //button[text()='Continue'])
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found

If I remove the Thread.sleep step, Its proceeding forward.
Can someone help me understand why is Thread.sleep causing this issue and how to resolve this ?

Below is the code:

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("enable-automation");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    
    driver.get("<ApplicationURL>");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("<some button to click>")).click();
```

Observation:
This issue is occurring when trying CHROME browser only and that too on MAC alone.
On Windows, this works fine.
FYI,
Chrome browser version: 108.0.5359.124
ChromeDriver version: 108.0.5359.71
MAC OS version : Monterey 12.6.2
Java version : 1.8.0_352
Selenium version : 3.11.0

Comment: You are trying to access some element after the browser closed, that's what the error says. Post your full code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a throws declaration for InterruptedException is necessary. If that is already added, then the error could be caused by the flow of the script. Depending on the wait for 2 seconds, the element may not be available.

Answer (score 0):

It may be happing but it we have implicit wait and explicit wait.. Lets use explicit wait instead of thread.sleep.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
driver.get("<ApplicationURL>");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("<some button to click>"));
wait..until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
element.click();
```